# How to adjust width of blog area when it has image and when image isn't there

Tags: php

How do I make blog area automatically resize when it has image and when it doesn't has image?

For example, I want blog area to be full width when it has no featured image set in wordpress and I want blog area to be 50% and image area to be 50% when featured image is set in blog.

Comment: This is lacking info and code. Also, have you done your research prior to posting this?

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.